# How to mock my classes correctly to make Contains method work?

Tags: c#, moq

I have 2 objects coming from the same class and when I try seeing if a list of the first object contains the other one, I can never get a true. Here's my example:

```
if (correspondingPins.Contains(pin) && pin.Channel != null)
{
         pins.Add(pin);
}
```

I can never go into the if statement.
The list of corresponding pins and the pin have the same class so it means they have the same parameters. I saw questions about it saying it's the refence that makes the 2 objects equal, but is it possible to access the refences and understand how the mocking works or anything else?

The objects have the same values except for 1 parameter which is the group. One could have 3 and the other 4. The other parameters are pin.Pin (string), pin.Channel and pin.Group. How could I mock a pin and make it equal to another pin while changing 1 parameter value ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(correspondingpins.Any(p=>p.pinNumber==pin.pinNumber) 
    && pin.Channel!=0)
...
```

You think the objects are different, so check by a value

Comment: It's what i thought I could do but there could be pins with the same pin numbers but different parameter values because when mocking, you need to set your parameters values and compare objects

Comment: We compare objects and not values of parameters because it is possible to have different pins with the same pin nunber

Comment: It seems you don't know yet what it means for some real world items to be equivalent. Is it pin + channel? When you've figured that out, use the .Any method.